# Quick implementation for very large indexed text search?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, solr, lucene, indexing

I have a single text file that is about 500GB (ie a very large log file) and would like to build an implementation to search it quickly.

So far I have created my own inverted index with a SQLite Database but this doesn't scale well enough.

Can anyone suggest a fairly simple implementation that would allow quick searching of this massive document?

I have looked at Solr and Lucene but these look too complicated for a quick solution, I'm thinking a database with built in full-text indexing (MySQl, Raven, Mongo etc.) may be the simplest solution but have no experience with this.

Comment: Would this file be able to fit onto the machine doing the searching ? Do you eventually need to split it into multiple parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are looking at text processing for log files I'd take a close look at the [Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/elasticsearch/) [Logstask](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/logstash/) [Kibana](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/kibana/) stack. Elasticsearch provides the Lucene based text search. Logstash parses and loads the log file into Elasticsearch. And Kibana provides a visualization and query tool for searching and analyzing the data.

This is a good webinar on the ELK stack by one of their trainers: http://www.elasticsearch.org/webinars/elk-stack-devops-environment/

As an experienced MongoDB, Solr and Elasticsearch user I was impressed by how it easy it was to get all three components up and functional analyzing log data. And it also has a robust user community, both here on stackoverflow and elsewhere.

You can download it here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/elkdownloads/

Comment: I've decided to go with the ELK stack after reviewing a few options. There is a prebuilt VM for anyone that is interested at http://logwrangler.mtcode.com/

Answer (score 0):

convert log file to csv then csv import to mysql, mongodb etc.

mongodb:

for help :

```
mongoimport --help
```

json file :

```
mongoimport --db db --collection collection --file collection.json
```

csv file :

```
mongoimport --db db--collection collection --type csv --headerline --file collection.csv
```

Use the “--ignoreBlanks” option to ignore blank fields. For CSV and TSV imports, this option provides the desired functionality in most cases: it avoids inserting blank fields in MongoDB documents.

link Guide:
[mongoimport](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) , [mongoimport v2.2](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/mongoimport/)

then define index on collection and enjoy :-)

Comment: Not sure how this will provide much of a benefit over his current system, especially if his working set is 500GB due to his queries.

Comment: I love mongodb but in this particular case the (stemming I think) was causing issues with exact matches with full-text indexing enabled